# wordpress get woocommerce price is wrong

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a simple xml for all my products in my woocommerce.

I already have build most of it, but I simply cant get the current product price in the loop:

```
<?php
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
    header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<STORE/>');
    $products = $xml->addChild('PRODUCTS');

    // Setup your custom query
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() && $count<1) {
        $count++;
        $loop->the_post();

        $wcProduct = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );

        $pr = $wcProduct->get_price_html();

        $product = $products->addChild('PRODUCT');
        $product->addChild('PRODUCT_URL', get_permalink(get_the_ID()));
        $product->addChild('PRODUCT_NAME', get_the_title());
        $product->addChild('price', $pr);

    }
    wp_reset_query();

    print($xml->asXML());

?>
```

it gives something relevant, any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$pr = $wcProduct->price;` should be all you need in the loop instead of the `get_price_html` call.